# Installing janus-gateway error on CentOS7

Tags: webrtc, centos7, janus, janus-gateway

I want to install janus-gateway on CentOS7.
I read the following document and tried installation.
https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/README.md

```
git clone https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git
cd janus-gateway
sh autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/opt/janus
```

However, configuring janus-gateway will cause an error. The error is as follows.

```
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for JANUS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
                    glib-2.0 >= 2.34
                                        libconfig
                    nice
                    jansson >= 2.5
                    libssl >= 1.0.1
                    libcrypto
                  ) were not met:

No package 'nice' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables JANUS_CFLAGS
and JANUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I installed libnice(libnice-0.1.3-4.el7.x86_64) in the following way.

```
yum install libnice
```

How can I solve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download libnice source code to install.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice

Answer (score 2):

try this and rebuild

```
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 when testing this.

If you are using Ubuntu system and trying to install Janus and running this code
`./configure --prefix=/opt/janus`

And then getting this error: `No package 'nice' found`

Make sure you have been installation of the nice from aptitude.

```
sudo install aptitude
aptitude install libmicrohttpd-dev libjansson-dev \
    libssl-dev libsrtp-dev libsofia-sip-ua-dev libglib2.0-dev \
    libopus-dev libogg-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev liblua5.3-dev \
    libconfig-dev pkg-config gengetopt libtool automake
```

For some reason installation of nice using the answer from Frank, Ahmet or Zallfire doesn't work in Ubuntu. It has to be installed using aptitude.

Comment: The question states the OS is CentOS7, not Ubuntu, so obviously, if you have to install something, the answers will not work for Ubuntu, as Ubuntu uses `apt` while CentOS uses `yum` (google "what is a package manager"). So basically, you are answering a different question here. You should not do that, but I will not flag this answer as it might be helpful to somebody who has this problem and is using a Debian flavored system.

Comment: Hi toydarian, I wasn't able to find a similar question for those running on Ubuntu and this was the closest thing I could google. Next time should I create a new question instead of adding to here?

Comment: Nah, I guess it is helpful for some other future Ubuntu users who see this, so it is okay. You just sounded puzzled, that other answers didn't work for you, so I added an explanation. Btw. you do not need to install `aptitude`, you can just use `apt install ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need the development libnice.

```
yum install libnice-devel
```